# How clear duplicate consecutive non-alphabetic characters in a string?

Tags: php, regex, duplicates, preg-replace, non-alphanumeric

Matching the string only for:  `,.:-` how I can remove duplicate values from a string? For example having:

```
"ab::::c ---------d,,,e ..........f ::a-b,,,c..d"
```

**Expected output:**

```
"ab:c -d,e .f :a-b,c.d"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are using `preg_replace` to achieve desired output.

**Regex:** `([,.:-])\1+` [**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9qCH8J/2)

Or

**Regex:** `(,|\.|:|-)\1+`[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9qCH8J/1)

> **1.** This will match a character and add that in captured group
>
> **2.** using that captured group for `\1` more than one occurence.

**Replacement:** `$1`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/807143)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string="ab::::c ---------d,,,e ..........f ::a-b,,,c..d";
echo preg_replace('/([,.:-])\1+/', '$1', $string);
```

**Solution 2:** `using foreach loop`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/807306)

```
$string="aab::::css ---------ddd,,,esddsff ..........f ::a-b,,,c..d";
$chars=  str_split($string);
$result=array();
foreach($chars as $character)
{
    if($character!=end($result) ||  !in_array($character, array(":",",",".","-")))
    {
        $result[]=$character;
    }
}
print_r(implode("",$result));
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, for maximum efficiency do not use piped characters in your pattern. The methods that are using loops are also making too many iterated function calls and/or conditionals.

Input: `$in="ab::::c ---------d,,,e ..........f ::a-b,,,c..d";`

Method #1: one-liner using `preg_replace()` (note empty replacement string)

```
echo preg_replace('/([,.:-])\K\1+/','',$in);
//                          ^^ resets the start of the matched substring
```

Method #2: one-liner using `preg_split()` & `implode()`

```
echo implode(preg_split('/([,.:-])\K\1+/',$in));  // empty glue doesn't need mentioning
```

Output using either method:

```
ab:c -d,e .f :a-b,c.d
```

I wonder which method is most efficient on this page.  If anyone would be so kind as to run and post a benchmark test with Sahil's 2 methods and my two methods, that would be very enlightening.

---

Here's a late consideration... If your string only has the problem of symbols repeating themselves before moving onto a valid character, then you can use this pattern: `[-.,:]\K[-.,:]+`  It will perform 50% faster than that all other patterns on this page and it offers the same output as the other methods on this page, but does stretch the interpretation of your question.  Here are some examples that expose the difference:

`ab:-,.c`;  will be reduced to `ab:c`
`ab:-,.c -d.,.e--f` will be reduced to `ab:c -d.e-f`

This may or may not be suitable for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> preg_replace — Perform a regular expression search and replace

```
$pattern = '/(\.|\,|\:|\-){2,}/';
$string = 'ab::::c ---------d,,,e ..........f ::a-b,,,c..d';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $string);
```

You can try your regular expressions here: https://regex101.com/